# Changing a div's background image doesn't work for me

Tags: jquery, css

I have browsed a bunch of threads on this topic before deciding to post my question here. None of those threads has answered my question or solved my problem (I have tried all solutions proposed there).

What I want to do is to display a bunch of thumbnails, and whenever the mouse is pointed at one of them, make the corresponding image the background. The background (and all screen elements) scale with window proportions. The image list can be quite long (it's a catalogue), so I don't want to exchange styles and classes. I want to change the page's background image.

My test bed is Google Chrome (recent version).

I am using jquery 3.3.1. My background is defined in a style:

```
.bgImage {
    background: url("http://www.descent2.de/Schmuck/images/title.jpg")  
no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function SetBackground (image)
       {
          // this doesn't work
          $('#background').css('background-image', 'url ("' + image.src + '")');
          // this doesn't work, too
          $('#background').css('background', 'url ("' + image.src + '")  
no-repeat center center fixed');
          // this still shows the old background image url
          alert ($('#background').css('background-image'));
       }
</head>

<body>
    <div id="background" class="bgImage">
    </div>

This code calls the background image changer. That works, I verified it.

<div id="thumbs">
    <article id="thumbs-content">
       <div class="thumb-size"><img class="thumb" id="thumb1" 

onmouseenter="SetBackground(this)" src="title.jpg"></div>
    </article>
</div>

</body>
```

First of all, defining the background image in the bgImage class style via a separate "background-image" statement doesn't work - no background image will be displayed at all, even when initally loading the page.

Also, neither changing the background image via "background-image", nor via "background" will work in the javascript function SetBackground().

Trying to retrieve the url of the current background name with

```
alert ($('#background').css ('background-image'));
```

returns the url of the old background image.

I have been trying to understand and to fix this for several hours and am completely stumped.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is the link to the full web site I am currently building (something very simple and basic): http://www.descent2.de/Schmuck/index.html

Comment: `$('#background')` needs the `#` to make it an id selector.

Comment: Correct, thanks, I fixed that. But changing the background image still doesn't work and the alert call now shows the old background image url after the attempt to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issues with the javascript function being called inline on multiple elements. It was returning your image source as undefined. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uaqyhz9w/2/) I got working for you. I think this is what you are attempting.

I removed your `onmousenter` function inline from the image element, and put it in a separate function. Doing that made it so `var img_src = $(this).attr("src");` would no longer return undefined. So the previous suggested solutions would work correctly. I hope the jsfiddle helps.

```
$('.thumb').mouseenter(function() {
  var img_src = $(this).attr("src");
  $('#background').css('background-image', 'url(' + img_src + ')');
});
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! I actually wanted to solve this via some function call tied to the class, but couldn't get it to work. That would have been my next question. What I don't understand is that changing the background image via the javascript function doesn't work. I have made sure the correct new image url goes in there.

Another question: I am using mouseenter, not hover, because I want the image to stay. Why does the statement "function (image)" need the image parameter? How should I have found out about that?

Comment: You can use `.hover` in place of `.mouseenter` or vice versa. Good catch on the callback function, you actually don't need to pass in `image` as a parameter. I did just to console log for testing and forgot to remove it when i realized there is no need for it. But since `$(this).attr("src")` returned the actual source this time, there is no need for image to be passed in as a parameter. Sorry to confuse you even more.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t have to send this as a parameter SetBackground() . In the function I would do $(this).attr("src"); So it would be like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
      <style type="text/css">
    .bgImage {
        background: url("http://www.descent2.de/Schmuck/images/title.jpg")  no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover; 
      }
      </style>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function SetBackground()
         {
          var current_src = $('#thumb1').attr("src");
          $('#background').css('background', 'url("' + current_src + '")');
         }
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="background" class="bgImage">
        </div>
        <div id="thumbs">
          <article id="thumbs-content">
             <div class="thumb-size"><img class="thumb" id="thumb1" onmouseenter="SetBackground()" src="title.jpg"></div>
          </article>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. If I try your version, img_src is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the double quotes are the issue.

This should work:

```
$('#background').css('background-image', 'url(' + image.src + ')');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not. I tried it both with and without them. Another thread stated they should be present.